# Is there a version of the BSD print system's `pac` command in the SVR4 print system

Tags: logs, printing

I was reading an old UNIX manual and one of the chapters was on UNIX printing systems. I am used to the BSD system(lpr/lpd) system, and found the `pac` command kind of cool. If you do not know what `pac` does, it gathers info for print jobs, and will calculate a printing price for the print jobs. The pricing model is customizable, and can be changed. Output would look something like:

```
Login                 pages/feet                   runs        price
user1                 10.00                        1           $10.00
user2                 100.00                       3           $300.00
user3                 1.00                         2           $2.00
```

later, the book went on to describe the SVR4 print system, which usesthe `lp` command to send a file to the print queue, and the `lpsched` daemon to print. But I have not seen any sort of `pac` command for the SVR4 system. Is there one? How do I use it?

Comment: Are you really using SVR4, or is it the emulation layer on top of CUPS?

Comment: Neither really. This was mainly out of curiosity. I may be trying out SmartOS which I believe is SVR4 based.

Comment: OK. I think the CUPS logfiles provide enough information to allow something like `pac` to be (re)written. I can't remember anything much about SVR4 printing, except that it was a pain to configure.